# How to run db:setup in Capistrano 3 and Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Just getting started with Capistrano 3, and I noticed on one of my first deploys for `my_app` that it was complaining about the MySQL database not existing.

```
DEBUG [aec39935]    ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: Unknown database 'my_app'
```

Well that's expected, since this a brand new deploy to a clean server. I included the `capistrano-rails` gem that's meant to take care of db migrations

```
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

I'd expect it to run `db:create` before `db:migrate` so that the database is created, but looks like it doesn't.

Is there a way for me to manually add this in, or reconfigure it so that it does run it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can either create a special task to do this, or just run `db:setup` manually once. I'd personally recommend the latter.

If you want to make a custom task, take a look at the rails/migration task as an example: https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake#L15